# Can't install <application> Try again, if it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix the problem. When i try to recieve new update from playstore

Tags: android, cordova, installation, google-play-console, android-11

01 September i deployed new update for my app. it says can't install update if it still doesn't work, see common ways to fix the issue. if somebody know about that issue . please give idea.

Answer (score -1):

That's because of i installed compiled apk from android studio and after try to update app via google play. uninstall already installed apk from studio compiled apk. before, installing from playstore.